# Join 2 datasets based on column and check for the next value if not present

Tags: scala, apache-spark, generics, apache-spark-sql

I have a requirement to join 2 data sets based on Key and version columns.

```
case class Sample(id: String, version: Int, recordValue: String)

val left = Seq(
     Sample("1", 5, "left5"),
     Sample("1", 6, "left6")
   ).toDS()

val right = Seq(
     Sample("1", 6, "right6"),
     Sample("1", 5, "right5"),
     Sample("1", 3, "right3"),
     Sample("1", 2, "right2"),
     Sample("1", 1, "right1")
   ).toDS()

val result = left.jointWith(right,
    left("id") === right("id") &&
    left("version") === (right("version")+1),
    "left_outer"
    )
```

I have to join the left DS with right DS so that I have a tuple of <current_version, previous_version> as mentioned below. If previous version is not present on the right side then I need to get the next previous version. For example: for version 6 (on left side, I need to get version 5 of right side

<version_6, version_5>
<version_5, version_3>

When joining for version 5 of left side, I need to get the version_3 of right side since version_4 is not present. The above join doesn't work get the next previous version if the immediate previous version doesn't exist.

Output should be as below

```
result.show()


result
================================
( (Sample("1", 6, "left6"), (Sample("1", 5, "right5"))
( (Sample("1", 5, "left5"), (Sample("1", 3, "right3"))
```

Thanks

Comment: One ugly option is to use a non-equi join (left version > right version) combined with using row_number to pick the highest right row for each ID.  Sorry, not sure how I'd write this in spark.

Answer (score 0):

You could `left-join` the Datasets with equal `id` and `left("version") > right("version")`, followed by a `groupBy` with [`max_by`](https://spark.apache.org/docs/3.3.0/api/scala/org/apache/spark/sql/functions$.html#max_by(e:org.apache.spark.sql.Column,ord:org.apache.spark.sql.Column):org.apache.spark.sql.Column) as the aggregating function.

```
val result = left.joinWith(
    right,
    left("id") === right("id") && left("version") > right("version"),
    "left_outer"
  ).
  groupBy($"_1".as("curr")).agg(max_by($"_2", $"_2.version").as("prev"))

result.show
// +-------------+--------------+
// |         curr|          prev|
// +-------------+--------------+
// |{1, 5, left5}|{1, 3, right3}|
// |{1, 6, left6}|{1, 5, right5}|
// +-------------+--------------+
```

Note that `max_by` is available only on `Spark 3.3+`.